# Porque Bootstrap 4 datepicker API não funciona?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

Estou a criar um calendário, algures na view, precisei de um input para o utilizador inserir uma data. Como estou a usar bootstrap 4 e o bootstrap tem vários addons para datepickers, usei um deles. Relativamente ao front-end, nada a dizer, funciona lindamente. Quando ao back-end, quando uso métodos, opções ou eventos da API em jquery, eles não executam.

```js
console.log($date = "data");
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
$date = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  console.log($date);
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CND -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Datapicker css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="sandbox-container" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true">
   <div class="input-group-addon" style="justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex: 0 0 25px;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="align-self: stretch"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[documentação]** - Tenho-me guiado pela documentação, possivelmente estarei a usar erradamente, conseguem identificar o erro?
[documentação](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Alguém me consegue ajudar?
Cumprimentos

**[update] 2/03/2019** - Opções já executam

> **Segundo a documentação:**
>   Data API
>   As with bootstrap’s own plugins, datepicker provides a data-api that can be used to instantiate datepickers without the need for custom javascript. For most datepickers, simply set ´data-provide="datepicker"´ on the element you want to initialize, and it will be intialized lazily, in true bootstrap fashion. For inline datepickers, use ´data-provide="datepicker-inline"´; these will be immediately initialized on page load, and cannot be lazily loaded.

Alterei o atributo `data-provide="datepicker"` para `data-provide="datepicker-inline"`, com isto esta parte do `jquery` já executou, contudo eventos ainda não são `dispachados`.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá fiz uns testes e o problema está em usar `INPUT` você deve usar `DIV` no datetimer, acho que existe uma biblioteca melhor que essa do bootstrap que você está usando, tente está aqui do [jQuery.UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Mas de qualquer forma assim funcionou basta tentar adaptar ao visual que você deseja.

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function(e){
    $date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  console.log($date);
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CND -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Datapicker css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="sandbox-container" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">
   <div id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true"></div>
   <div class="input-group-addon" style="justify-content: center;align-items: center;flex: 0 0 25px;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="align-self: stretch"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente a biblioteca sugerida á primeira vista parece ter um melhor desempenho. Contudo não resolve o problema inicial. Respondi á minha pergunta e consegui solucionar parte do problema, acha que consegue melhorar a minha resposta?

Comment: O que você deseja fazer? não intendi. quer inicializar ele com uma data que vem de uma api?

Comment: Basicamente, quando altero o attributo date-provide para "datepicker-inline", o datepicker carrega aquando o carregamento da página, ou seja, deixa de ser "lazely", assim quando executo o script, ele já pode ser inicializado.

Comment: ainda não consegui intender, colocando esse atributo ele carrega mais rápido?

Comment: Sim, mas não é só isso. Alterei a resposta, o código estava errado. Conheço o termo 'lazy' em outros contextos da programação, neste não sei como funciona. Por exemplo, imagina que tens uma propriedade "altura=5cm", depois fazes setAltura(8cm), contudo se a propriedade for 'lazy' a altura continua a ser 5cm. Agora, se fizeres um getAltura(), a altura muda para o valor do último set e retorna 8cm. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pregui%C3%A7osa

Comment: Neste caso, o calendário sendo 'lazy', só inicia momentos antes de ser usado. Daí o script não executar nenhuma das funções. Falta-me encontrar um método/evento que disperte assim que ele for inicializado.

Answer (score 1):

**[Quase-Resolvido]**

**API de dados**
Assim como os próprios plug-ins do bootstrap, o datepicker fornece uma API de dados que pode ser usada para instanciar datepickers sem a necessidade de um javascript personalizado.
Para a maioria dos datepickers, simplesmente defina data-provide = "datepicker" no elemento que você deseja inicializar, e ele será inicializado preguiçosamente, na forma de bootstrap verdadeira.

**[Por resolver]** - Nestes casos ainda não sei que código jquery espera pela inicialização do datepicker.
Tentei

```
$('.datepicker').ready(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $date = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log($date);
            });
        });
```

[debbuging] - entra na função cedida em ready, mas não executa opções nem eventos.

**[Revolvido]** -  Para in-line, use data-provide = "datepicker-inline"; estes serão inicializados imediatamente no carregamento da página e não podem ser carregados com preguiça.

Desta forma alterando o HTML

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker-inline" id="sandbox-container" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        console.log('Aqui');
        $date = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
        console.log($date);
        });
    });
```